# Facebook Python OAuth Desktop Application

Tags: python, facebook, oauth, facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to create a desktop application with Python for logging into Facebook, and then it would use the Facebook GraphAPI. However I cannot figure out how to get the access token that I need. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a guide that explains the steps to get a Facebook OAuth token: http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/

Comment: That is a guide for web applications. The mentions of desktop applications aren't enough to construct anything around. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: but the process is the same.  you'll need a method in which you display a webpage for authentication.  you can use some of the http automation libraries in python to handle this, but then the user will be giving your app their user/pass which is expressly what oauth is trying to avoid.  look at the "webbrowser" package if you need info on how to launch the user's default browser